# Solving a crackme with z3py

Tags: z3py

I want to solve a crackme with Z3. The crackme is pretty huge, but it can be simplified to what follows::

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
T='Fguad2x-GP5_QqNi'
key=sys.argv[1]

if len(key) != 3:
    print "Bad key length"
    exit(1)

out=[]
for c in key:
    out.append(T[ord(c)>>4 ])
    out.append(T[ord(c) & 0xf])

if ''.join(out)=='--xPxN':
    print "You win"
```

The solution is 'win'.

This sort of things could be solved with z3 I guess. I begin with translated all logic from crackme in a z3 style:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from z3 import *

#Preparing data
map_array='Fguad2x-GP5_QqNi'
T=Array('T',IntSort(),IntSort())
for i,j in enumerate(map_array):
    T = Store(T, ord(j), i)
sol='--xPxN'

#We know input has 3 characters
a=BitVec('a',8)
b=BitVec('b',8)
c=BitVec('c',8)

#Ignite
s=Solver()

#String key is printable
s.add(BV2Int(a)>=65,BV2Int(a)<=122)
s.add(BV2Int(b)>=65,BV2Int(b)<=122)
s.add(BV2Int(c)>=65,BV2Int(c)<=122)

#Adding constraints
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(a>>4))==ord(sol[0]))
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(a&0xf))==ord(sol[1]))
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(b>>4))==ord(sol[2]))
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(b&0xf))==ord(sol[3]))
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(c>>4))==ord(sol[4]))
s.add(Select(T,BV2Int(c&0xf))==ord(sol[5]))

#Verify solving
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

Now, I have some questions:

- s.check() says 'sat' so I have at least one solution?
- is there a better way to define an array?
- is there a way to use the characters directly?
- How to get only a, b and c after solution? s.model() shows a very strange output:

  $ ./stovlfw.py

  sat
  [b = 1,
   a = 136,
   c = 0,
   T = [3 -> 78,
        65 -> 120,
        2 -> 80,
        1 -> 45,
        0 -> 45,
        else -> 45],
   k!0 = [3 -> 78,
          65 -> 120,
          2 -> 80,
          1 -> 45,
          0 -> 45,
          else -> 45]]

This seems to be in contradiction with constraints (??) I'm doing something wrong, but where?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in z3 don't behave as their C counterpart. They should not be used to model small finite collections of values. It is usually much more efficient to create different variables using list comprehensions.

Here's my alternative approach. Make a Function in z3 that lets you choose nth char from a string.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from z3 import *

#Preparing data
nth = Function('nth', StringSort(), IntSort(), BitVecSort(8))
final = String('final')
sol='--xPxN'

#We know input has 3 characters
a=BitVec('a',8)
b=BitVec('b',8)
c=BitVec('c',8)

#Ignite
s=Solver()

#Adding constraints
for i,j in enumerate('Fguad2x-GP5_QqNi'):
    s.add(nth(final,i)==ord(j))

s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(a>>4))==ord(sol[0]))
s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(a&0xf))==ord(sol[1]))
s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(b>>4))==ord(sol[2]))
s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(b&0xf))==ord(sol[3]))
s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(c>>4))==ord(sol[4]))
s.add(nth(final,BV2Int(c&0xf))==ord(sol[5]))

#String key is printable
s.add((a)>=65,(a)<=122)
s.add((b)>=65,(b)<=122)
s.add((c)>=65,(c)<=122)

#Verify solving Fguad2x-GP5_QqNi
print s.check()
print s.model()
print ''.join(chr(s.model()[i].as_long()) for i in [a,b,c])
```

`s.model()` can be used as a dict to retrieve variable values.

PS : upgrade your z3 to latest version for this to work.